# Markdown in Docfx file inclusion passing parameters

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, docfx

How to pass parameters to an included file?

File inclusion works:

```
[!include[file2](file2.md)]
```

But I want to pass parameters. Something like:

```
{% include "file2.md" with
    {
        "name": "x"
    }
%}
```

file2.md:

```
# Hi {{name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported in DocFX. You can open a feature request in https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues

Comment: I have asked a DocFX question here if you are interested in answering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018471/namespaces-not-wrapping-properly-with-ie11